# Python times table using while

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Why in python a *times table* program doesn't work like this?

```
n = int(input("Type a number: "))
count = 10
while count < 0:
    print(f"{count} x {n} = {n * count}")
    count = count - 1
```

But this works correctly:

```
n = int(input("Type a number: "))
for i in range(1, 11):
    print(f"{i} x {n} = {n * i}")
```

The result is (or should be), for example:

> 1 x 5 = 5
>
> 2 x 5 = 10
>
> 3 x 5 = 15
>
> 4 x 5 = 20
>
> 5 x 5 = 25
>
> 6 x 5 = 30
>
> 7 x 5 = 35
>
> 8 x 5 = 40
>
> 9 x 5 = 45
>
> 10 x 5 = 50

As a beginner I need to understand... and is it possible to use *while* in that situation?
This is python 3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the condition in the `while` to be true to go through the loop. Thus we will say do while count is greater than or equal to zero.

```
n = int(input("Type a number: "))
count = 10
while count >= 0:
    print(f"{count} x {n} = {n * count}")
    count = count - 1
```

Comment: That prints the list in reverse.

Comment: Yeah, the OP has that part figured out. The answer addresses the syntax with which to define the condition in a while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You want to start `count` from 1 so that your loop increments rather than decrements. Your while loop conditional check is also incorrect as `count` is *never* less than 0. Try this:

```
n = int(input("Type a number: "))
count = 1
while count <= 10:
    print(f"{count} x {n} = {n * count}")
    count = count + 1
```